# Does the following self-join select records from table1 that have a duplicate record in table1?

Tags: sql, duplicates, self-join

```
SELECT r1.*

FROM [Table1] AS r1, [Table1] AS r2

WHERE 
  r1.[Employee]=  r2.[Employee] and
  r1.[Machine Type]=  r2.[Machine Type] and
  r1.[Machine number]=  r2.[Machine number] and
  r1.[Employee Last Name]=  r2.[Employee Last Name] and
  r1.[Employee First Name]=  r2.[Employee First Name] and
  r1.[Employee Number]=  r2.[Employee Number] and
  r1.[Shift]=  r2.[Shift] and
  r1.[Department]=  r2.[Department] and
  r1.[Position]=  r2.[Position]

ORDER BY 
r1.[Employee], 
r1.[Machine Type], 
r1.[Machine number], 
r1.[Employee Last Name], 
r1.[Employee First Name], 
r1.[Employee Number], 
r1.[Shift], 
r1.[Department], 
r1.[Position]
```

When I run this code on Table1, it selects ~33,000 records from ~63,000.  Is it selecting records that have duplicates records based on the fields that are listed in the query?

Comment: Yes, if we assume that a "duplicate" means the same values for 9 columns.  You might want to add sample data and give us a smaller reproducible problem.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Tim, yes i meant that all 9 columns collectively create a duplicate record to another.  I will add a sample to my post.

Comment: marc_s, Thank you.  I will read the content.  I am relatively new to SQL, so i want to learn best practices.

Comment: If i used a LEFT OUTER JOIN, would that include records that do not have a duplicate record, as well as those that do?

Comment: Actually, i just tried LEFT OUTER JOIN and of course, it doesn't help because it returns all records as well as duplicated records, which is the same as the original table.

Comment: Okay i made a big mistake in my original post.  Originally, r1 = Table1, and r2 = Table2.  But r2 also equals Table1.